# Does making local aliases of variables speed up list comprehensions as it does loops?

Tags: python, optimization

Name lookups are relatively expensive in Python, so for large loops you can get a performance advantage by changing something like

```
for element in my_list:
    do_something(element)
```

to something like

```
ds = do_something
for element in my_list:
    ds(element)
```

so that the interpreter only has to look up a local variable on each iteration. Is this optimization also useful if the function is being invoked by a list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, local names in functions are faster to look up than globals or attributes on objects.

Comment: And the title changed rather dramatically since you posted. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I totally changed the framing of my question but forgot about the title :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I set up a simple example using `timeit`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import timeit

setup = '''
def return_five():
    return 6

def f1():
    return [return_five() for i in range(10000)]

def f2():
    r = return_five
    return [r() for i in range(10000)]
'''

print('Not a local variable:')
print(min(timeit.Timer('a = f1()', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))

print('Local variable:')
print(min(timeit.Timer('a = f2()', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
```

A typical result of this script was

```
Not a local variable:
1.22310686111
Local variable:
1.17974805832
```

I was surprised to see that the second function, `f2`, was consistently about 3.5% faster than the first function. I was expecting that Python would only look up `return_five` once when it encountered the list comprehension in `f1`, but it seems to look it up each time.

(Presumably this is so that the list comprehension behaves correctly if one of the functions involved has the side effect of changing the name lookup somehow. That seems like a pretty pathological side effect to me, but I guess it’s better to be slightly inefficient than to introduce an optimization that could cause hard-to-track-down bugs.)

When I changed the size of the list comprehensions from 10,000 to 10, the gap closed so that `f2` was only 0.8% faster than `f1`. This confirms that the function name lookup is being performed on each iteration through the loop.

Comment: I can confirm the difference in CPython 2.7.5, however in Python 3.3.3 the results are on par. Sometimes `f2` took even longer.

So the lesson here is, *do not rely on (current) implementation's behavior unless it's defined as a part of the language* .