# perfomance of len(List) vs reading a variable

Tags: python, performance

A similar question has already been ask [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function) here. However, this question looks at the cost of `len` it self. 
Suppose, I have a code that repeats many times `len(List)`, every time is `O(1)`, reading a variable is also `O(1)` plus assigning it is also `O(1)`.

As a side note, I find that `n_files = len(Files)` is somewhat more readable than repeated `len(Files)` in my code. So, that is already an incentive for me to do this.
You could also argue against me, that somewhere in the code `Files` can be modified, so `n_files` is no longer correct, but that is not the case.

My question is:
Is the a number of calls to `len(Files)` after which accessing `n_files` 
will be faster?

Comment: Given that Python will have to go and look up `len` each time, the number is probably 1. But why not do some tests and find out? As both approaches are `O(1)` this is all about the fixed costs.

Comment: I thought that `len` would be cheaper compared to the creation of a new `int` instance ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then what about doing `len_func = len` and then calling `len_func(Files)`?

Comment: Note that small integers are interned in CPython, so if your list is shorter than `255` (IIRC) you'll get the same instance.

Comment: @DeepSpace that's a good question - locally aliasing functions is one way to boost performance, and that may make the comparison much tighter. There's still the function *call*, though.

Comment: @DeepSpace Doesn't that require that you'll have to lookup `len_func` instead?

Comment: @skyking yes, but the local lookup is faster than the global one. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20388114/3001761

Comment: What are you actually doing that  you  worried about an `0(1)` operation?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, because `O(1)` can be 5 ms, or 500ms, and I am trying to understand Python better, not just to be a `coder`... Asking this question here will also (hopefully, help others too...)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few results (time, in seconds, for one million calls), with a ten-element list using Python 2.7.10 on Windows 7; `store` is whether we store the length or keeping calling `len`, and `alias` is whether or not we create a local alias for `len`:

```
Store Alias n=      1      10     100
Yes   Yes       0.862   1.379   6.669
Yes   No        0.792   1.337   6.543
No    Yes       0.914   1.924  11.616
No    No        0.879   1.987  12.617
```

and a thousand-element list:

```
Store Alias n=      1      10     100
Yes   Yes       0.877   1.369   6.661
Yes   No        0.785   1.299   6.808
No    Yes       0.926   1.886  11.720
No    No        0.891   1.948  12.843
```

Conclusions:

- Storing the result is more efficient than calling `len` repeatedly, even for `n == 1`;
- Creating a local alias for `len` can make a small improvement for larger `n` where we aren't storing the result, but not as much as just storing the result would; and
- The influence of the length of the list is negligible, suggesting that whether or not the integers are interned isn't making any difference.

Test script:

```
def test(n, l, store, alias):
    if alias:
        len_ = len
        len_l = len_(l)
    else:
        len_l = len(l)
    for _ in range(n):
        if store:
            _ = len_l
        elif alias:
            _ = len_(l)
        else:
            _ = len(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from itertools import product
    from timeit import timeit
    setup = 'from __main__ import test, l'
    for n, l, store, alias in product(
        (1, 10, 100),
        ([None]*10,),
        (True, False),
        (True, False),
    ):
        test_case = 'test({!r}, l, {!r}, {!r})'.format(n, store, alias)
        print test_case, len(l),
        print timeit(test_case, setup=setup)
```

Answer (score 2):

Function calls in python are costly, so if you are 100% sure that the size of `n_files` would not change when you are accessing its length from the variable, you can use the variable, if that is what is more readable for you as well.

An Example performance test for both accessing `len(list)` and accessing from variable , gives the following result -

```
In [36]: l = list(range(100000))

In [37]: n_l = len(l)

In [40]: %timeit newn = len(l)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 92.8 ns per loop

In [41]: %timeit new_n = n_l
10000000 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ns per loop
```

Accessing the variable is always faster than using `len()` .

Answer (score 1):

Using `l = len(li)` is faster:

```
python -m timeit -s "li = [1, 2, 3]" "len(li)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.239 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "li = [1, 2, 3]; l = len(li)" "l"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0949 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `len(Files)` instead of `n_files` is likely to be slower. Yes you have to lookup `n_files`, but in the former case you'll have to lookup both `len` and `Files` and then on top of that call a function that "calculates" the length of `Files`.

Comment: What do you feel this adds to the previous answers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's an theoretical explaination why it should be faster. Two of the answers are more or less just experimental test to see which is fastest and Anands only points out that function calls are costly (which it may be).

Comment: Removed some of the answer which was false
Currently, Python does not calculate the length of lists. It is strored as a varaible within the object. 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Objects/listobject.c#L379

Comment: @DonCarleone In this case "calculation" can be considered as just O(1) operation

Comment: @fdermishin 
cal·cu·late 
/ˈkalkyəˌlāt/ 
verb
1.
determine (the amount or number of something) _mathematically_.